# Proficient way to check if 3 variables are all unique

Tags: algorithm, perl, optimization

I wanted to write a script that checks if 3 variables (A,B,C) are all unique and dont equal each other. I thought of just doing a big if statement like:

```
if (A != B) && (A != C) && (B != C){
    // do function }
```

I was just wondering if there is another way? Because the code looks kindof clunky. This is in Perl.

Comment: Well it looks *fine* to me.

Comment: Assuming 3 variables are involved, I'd stick with it. I'd maybe use `and` rather than `&&`, but that's about it. If we're talking larger numbers of comparisons, it'd get unwieldy though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Abstracting complicated details (e.g. those that "look clunky") is the point of subs. Move the logic to a sub if you don't like seeing it. Personally, that looks fine for me for three variables.

Note that if you're moving the code to a sub, you might consider using an O(N) algorithm. Your current approach scales poorly (O(N<sup>2</sup>)).

```
sub are_distinct {
   my %seen;
   ++$seen{$_} for @_;
   return keys(%seen) == @_;
}
```

---

Optimized to exit as soon as possible:

```
sub are_distinct {
   my %seen;
   for (@_) {
      return 0 if $seen{$_}++;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the uniq function from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) to get all of the unique elements, then compare the length to your original number of elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq); 

my ($A, $B, $C) = (1, 2, 3);
my @elems = ($A, $B, $C);

if ( uniq(@elems) == @elems ) {
   # do function
}
```

Comment: No need to `use` a special function to solve this problem. Just use a hash table.

Comment: Why would I write my own uniq function when one already exists in a common module.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function,

```
sub all_unique {
  my %seen;
  return (@_ == grep !$seen{$_}++, @_);
}

if (all_unique($A, $B, $C)) { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

With three variables, there is nothing really "big", just three comparisons.

If you want to generalize to more variables, say N, then it becomes useful to be more efficient.

If you compare exhaustively, you need `N(N-1)/2` comparisons (e.g. `N=10 -> 45`).

A better way is to sort and then use `N-1` comparisons (e.g. N=10 -> 9: `A!=B && B!=C && C!=D` ...).

Comment: Surely you have to make the same comparisons whilst sorting as you would to determine uniqueness?

Comment: Sorting will be O(N log N) + the O(N) for the later comparisons = O(N log N), which is larger than the optimal O(N). It will yeild longer code N=3. It will yield shorter code for N=10, but only if avoiding writing a sub was a good thing.

Comment: For general data types, element uniqueness is an Omega(N Log N) problem. How could you achieve O(N) ??

Comment: @Yves Daoust, Not sure what you're talking about. I've already posted an Omega(N) solution.

Comment: @ikegami: agreed, hashing can make it in linear time if you can control collisions (I assume you meant an O(N) solution).

Answer (score -1):

I'd do this in .NET with a `HashSet<T>`:

```
var myVariables = new List<int> { A, B, C };
var hashset = new HashSet<int>(myVariables);
if (hashset.Count != myVariables.Count)
{
    // There was at least one duplicate value / hash collision
}
```

I imagine there are similar data structures in PERL and so forth. :)